Is there an issue with downloading a zip file under .NET Core?
I have a problem downloading a zip file with .NET Core. I have a function that works locally. As soon as I publish it, I get this error:

The controller looks like this:
public class SpecialController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();   
    }

    public FileResult Download()
    {
         var fileName = "TCProjects.zip";
         var stream = new FileStream("zipfile/TCProjects.zip", FileMode.Open);
         return File(stream, "application/zip", fileName);
    }
}

I am using an action link in the Special View like this:
<a href="@Url.Action("Download")">DownLoad TCProjects</a>

As soon as I select this link, I get the error. I have not had much experience downloading files in net core so I am a bit lost on how to correct this.

Please kindly check if zipfile folder and TCProjects.zip file are exist or not under wwwroot in your publish files. For more details, you can try to include zipfile folder during the deployment.

May I know if you have any other questions about this issue?

After many attempts to resolve this, I realized I was having a server issue regarding permissions. The website on the server was changed to use a user pool.

If this problem only occurs in the code you shared, then we only need to check whether there is a zipfile folder and a TCProjects.zip file under wwwroot in your release files directory.
The reason for this problem is that during the build/publish process, the zipfile folder and all the files under this folder are not included. We can include it by using the settings below.
your.csproj
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="zipfile\**">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>

Tips
Make sure you also enable UseStaticFiles or UseDefaultFiles middleware in your Program.cs file.
